# How can I generate this waveform?

Tags: microcontroller, dac, waveform, function-generator

I am trying to generate this waveform:

[image]

basically a ramped square wave with a maximum frequency of 1KHz.

My first thought was to use the DAC pin of a microcontroller, but are there any ICs that can do this?

Comment: Can you use test equipment? Many function generators have an arbitrary waveform option.

Comment: Looks like superposition of two signals.

Comment: @mattman944 is there an IC that has an arbitrary waveform option? I need this signal to be generated on-board.

Comment: This is trivial for a fixed f , CC into a cap that limits on V. Why is it important?

Comment: A NE556 with a couple passive components would do a close approximation, so that’s single-chip. How precise do you need the shape, ie. how many % deviation from ideal shape is allowed? Otherwise, a quad op-amp like LM2902 or TL074 would work as well, configured into a suitable circuit. Cost? $3/100 pcb + components. Tossing a microcontroller around it is trivial, but where’s the fun in that – and I’m the guy who tosses microcontrollers at most everything :)

Comment: Each half looks like a clipped sawtooth. If you want a creative solution then you’ll need to give us the full picture of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple one chip, one display, function generator circuit that could be slightly modified (in software) to produce a signal nearly identical to what you need. In fact there is an example wave form that the author calls a "chainsaw" that is already very close to what you want.  http://www.technoblogy.com/show?20W6

Later update w/PCB:
http://www.technoblogy.com/show?2FCL

If you require a bipolar waveform you could reference your output ground to 1/2 the supply voltage, for example +2.5v in this case. So with the generator circuit running with a +5v supply you could easily create an output  (bipolar) waveform output of 2.5vpp.

If you don't think you would ever need to adjustment the signal then you might even leave out the display and adjustment components to save costs.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you could improvise an analogue circuit that would approximate well, but a $2 micro seems like a good solution.  I’m not aware of a single IC that would do it but it’s an interesting exercise for whatever the equivalent of code golf is.

Comment: Others mentioned that many function generators have an arbitrary waveform option. Do any waveform generator ICs have that option as well?

Comment: Not that I’m aware of, you can get done, square, triangular from off-the-shelf ICs but an AWG is essentially a micro with a DAC.

Comment: Given the simplicity of the thing, a completely analog solution would be single chip too – external passive components just to configure the wave shape, quite literally. Probably no semiconductors save for the single chip itself.